# XPath extract first part of Span with Strong nested inside

Tags: xpath

The xml file is as follows:

```
<span>foo
  <strong>bar</strong>
</span>
```

I want to be able to create an XPath which returns "foo" **and not** "bar". `//span[1]` returns "foo bar".

How do I have to change my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//span/text()
```

returns all text nodes which are direct children of `//span` (here: "foo").

---

`//span[1]` which you tried returns the first `<span/>` element with all its contents, so it actually should return `foo<strong>bar</strong>`. If you want to return only the first text node, extend the query above like this:

```
//span/text()[1]
```

For an input like

```
<span>
  foo
  <strong>bar</strong>
  batz
</span>
```

which would result in "foobatz" otherwise, it will still limit the result set to "foo".

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
xpath string(//span/strong)
```

that was how i used it in xmllint shell. you can use the function `string` directly.

Comment: This returns "bar", *not* "foo". The question is the other way round.

Comment: @JensErat well in that case , the xml given here is not in a preferred format. All the data are expected within different tags.


`<span>
<newtag>foo</newtag>
<strong>bar</strong>
</span>`

or you can even try adding attributes..

`<span attr="foo">`

Comment: The XML above is syntactically totally fine and there are reasonable examples for it. Think of `<p>Foo <strong>bar</strong> batz.</p>` which is a valid X(HT)ML snippet.

Comment: @JensErat i agree that syntactically correct. i was jus mentioning abt usage practices. +1 to ur answer.